# C# in VS2005: can you check whether an integer is declared in a given Enum type?

Tags: c#, enums

For C# in VS2005, is there way to check if an integer is part of a Enum type?

eg:

```
if number in CustomerType { ... }
```

where

```
enum CustomerType
{
    A = 0;
    B = 1;
    C = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is [Enum.IsDefined(Type enumType, Object value)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) what you're looking for?

Instead of your if-statement:

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(CustomerType), number))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var value = Enum.GetName(typeof(CustomerType), 3); // instead of 3 you can use any value
```

where `CustomerType` is:

```
public enum CustomerType
{
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 2,
}
```

By passing 3 value will have a null value. If you pass an existing value (i.e. 0, 1 or 2) then you'll get "A", "B" or "C".

For further info you can check the static methods of the `System.Enum` class.

Regards...